# Specifying generic to function call is breaking other type safety checks

Tags: typescript

Given the code below,

```
type Definition<R> = {
  actions: Record<string, number>
}

export function defineResource<R extends object = object, D extends Definition<R> = Definition<R>>(definition: D) {
  return (resource: R) => {
    return {
      can(user: any, actionKey: keyof D['actions']) {
        return true
      },
    }
  }
}

const myResource = defineResource<{ something: number }>({ // <- with generic
    actions: {
        create: 100,
        delete: 100,
    }
})

myResource({ something: 123 }).can({}, 'test') // <- does not complain
```

As you can see, in my last line, I am passing `'test'` and TypeScript is not complaining. That's not what I want—I want the `actionKey` of my `can` method to accept only `create` or `delete`, which were specified by the `actions` object specified at `defineResource(...)`.

Turns out it works when I do not pass any generic to the `defineResource` function call, as in:

```
const myResource = defineResource({ // <- without generic
    actions: {
        create: 100,
        delete: 100,
    }
})

myResource({ something: 123 }).can({}, 'test') // <- complains
```

The problem by not specifying a generic to `defineResource<>` is that I cannot enforce the object passed at `myResource()` to respect a given schema.

**The above said, how can I make sure `actionKey` enforces type safety while being able to specify the schema `myResource` is expecting?**

Playground: https://tsplay.dev/wR7JQN

Comment: Yuck, I think you'll need currying for this since partial type inference isn't supported: https://tsplay.dev/Woxlgw

Comment: Aw, sad. So ugly. But well, it is what it is. I think that will do for now. Thanks!